# Error from angular migration, 2.1.x => 4.1.3

Tags: angular, webpack, migration

I am working on updating quite a hefty project, that is way past due on its update schedule.

I am getting an error related to browserdomadapter:

> Property 'query' does not exist on type 'BrowserDomAdapter'.

Here is the code:

```ts
constructor(titleService: Title) {

  this.titleService = titleService;

  this.dom = new BrowserDomAdapter();

  this.headElement = this.dom.query('head');
  this.metaDescription = this.getOrCreateMetaElement('description');
  this.robots = this.getOrCreateMetaElement('robots');
}
```

and:

```ts
private getOrCreateMetaElement(name: string): HTMLElement {
    let el: HTMLElement; 
    el = this.dom.query('meta[name=' + name + ']'); 
    if (el === null) {
        el = this.dom.createElement('meta'); 
        el.setAttribute('name', name);
        this.headElement.appendChild(el);
    }
    return el;
}
```

I also had to migrate from webpack 1.x.x to the latest as well.

Comment: Check [**this issue**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8509).

Comment: Always good to google/search you problem in the issue tracker of angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BrowsDomAdapter is no longer supported. The new method is to inject DOCUMENT.

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({})
export class MyClass {

    constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }

    doSomething() {
        this.document.someMethodOfDocument();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is just copy pasted from the link that @developer commented before...

Comment: I was reading through that entire thread before any comment was posted until I found the solution which I made available, and makes it so that he doesn't have to crawl old issue threads and makes the answer clearly available to any others that may stumble on this problem.

Comment: its k, most of the new angular related questions in SO are from ppl that dont know how to google or either check the issue tracker in github